# Count attributes with certain value xPath

Tags: xpath, adobe, livecycle

Currently i'm trying to count the total of items that are selected with xpath.

to count all items i can do:

```
count(/process_data/formData/xdp/datasets/data/Data//@selected)
```

but how can i count all items where the value of selected is true. (not knowing the previous node). If i knew the previous node i could do:

```
count(/process_data/formData/xdp/datasets/data/Data//node[@selected=true]/@selected)
```

but since i don't know this data, i can't use this. any ideas?

Comment: `//node` makes no sense for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by *not knowing the previous node* that you want to check all nodes that may have a `selected` attribute I think you just have to change your XPath expression to:

```
count(/process_data/formData/xdp/datasets/data/Data//*[@selected='true'])
```

This assumes that `selected` is actually a string attribute.